# Adding attributes in LINQ using element.add

Tags: attributes, linq-to-xml, addition

I have to write information from textboxes to XML file on click event.
My sample code would look lik this.

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

        xmlDoc.Element("Mediaplans").Add(new XElement("MediaPlan", new XElement("Media",TxtMedia.Text),
        new XElement("Adtype", TxtAdtype.Text), new XElement("EmailId",TxtEmailId.Text)));

        xmlDoc.Save(fileName).
```

What I want to know is how do we add attributes to elements with the above method?
I am new to this field. any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Kruthika

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Add` and pass an `XAttribute` too.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use add new XAttribute like you have done with XElement.

Have a look at [this](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx) link for an example

I believe that you should be able to do something like

`XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);`

xmlDoc.Element("Mediaplans").Add(new XAttribute("File name", fileName),new XElement("MediaPlan", new XElement("Media",TxtMedia.Text), new XElement("Adtype", TxtAdtype.Text), new XElement("EmailId",TxtEmailId.Text));

xmlDoc.Save(fileName).

Sorry dont have access to VS at the moment so I cant verify the code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. what I was looking for is dynamically add nodes when a click event occurs. The example seems to be about adding nodes statically, By using element.Add, I am only being able to add a new Xelement, If I have a XAttribute ot be added to one of the Xelements, what is the syntax for using it?

Comment: See my updated reply. Let me know if it doesnt work and I will try and verify it.